# Could not build Objective-C module 'GoogleMobileAds'

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, admob

I did like in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXZ7jpgfVoc).

I tried cleaning but did not solved.I added GoogleMobileAds.framework

The errors is  "`..ViewController.swift:12:8: Could not build Objective-C module 'GoogleMobileAds''`"

line 12: `import GoogleMobileAds`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was facing the same problem while following tutorial from Google (https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start)

I also tried @Luda solution by adding Manually and succeed. After that, I decide to try again with CocoaPods by using Bridging-Header (same way with adding Analytics Lib):

- Follow tutorial here to add Bridging Header http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/
- Add `#import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>` to your Bridging Header
- Clean and Build again, it will success.

Comment: Doesn't work for Xcode 8 apperently; it says `GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h not found` even thought it's in my project.

Comment: @JozemiteApps Same here. Were you able to solve this issue ? I am stuck with same

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is installing GoogleMobileAds framework manually.
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/ios/quick-start#manually_using_the_sdk_download

Answer (score 1):

After searching and searching through Stackoverflow and nothing helping, I finally just deleted the entire GoogleMobileAds folder from my project (not just the reference, I deleted the actual folder in the pod folder). I also removed all references to GoogleMobileAds and ran `pod install` and it finally fixed it.

Comment: This worked for me, I also commented-out the pod and ran pod install to get Cocoapods to delete the pod correctly, then ran it again to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your build setting and change Defines Module to "yes"

Answer (score 0):

The modules where introduced in iOS 6.0.

If you want to use the GoogleMobileAds module, you have to change your app minimum deployment target to 6.0 at least.

See that [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_6_0.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but since I figured out my issue and it has not been listed here I thought I would share. I was having the same error and I tried everything and nothing worked. I finally read [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/103) and the last comment the poster talks about downloading the file in windows and then moving it to a Mac caused him issues.

Well that's why I was having the error. Once I downloaded the file from the mac BAM! it worked.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old thread but I will add my solution here because it happened to me today.

Change your Deployment target to at least 6.0